# Efficiency of a Rankine cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

So the efficiency of a Rankine cycle is given by the formula $$e=1-\frac{Q_{c}}{Q_{h}}=1-\frac{H_{4}-H_{1}}{H_{3}-H_{2}} \approx 1-\frac{H_{4}-H_{1}}{H_{3}-H_{1}}$$

I understand that the change in enthalpy equals to the heat absorbed/expelled. But there's a few things I don't understand about the efficiency

1. Why is $Q_{c} = {H_{4}-H_{1}}$ and not $Q_{c} = {H_{1}-H_{4}}$ since the cycle goes from point 4 back to point 1, and a change is defined as $\Delta x=x_{f}-x_{i}$ where f stands for final, and i for initial.
2. Why can we make the approximation that $H_{2} \approx H_{1}$. (Schroeder says that it's a good approximation since the pump adds very little energy to the water, while the $PV$ term in $H$ is very small for liquids.)

**EDIT:**

Since I didn't provide an image for the Rankine cycle here is the one they use in Schroeder:

[image]

Comment: You should include a diagram of the cycle identifying the equilibrium states 1,2,3 and 4, just to make sure there is no misunderstanding.

Comment: Well, the sign of the change in $Q$ depends on how you are looking at it. Yes, to the internal state of the heat engine you are correct. But from the cold reservoir's point of view $H_{4} - H_{1}$ is correct. Since the efficiency is about the external (reservoir) inputs and outputs, the book is correct. I understand the confusion, its all about keeping track of what goes where and the appropriate sign(s) to use.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a diagram of the cycle identifying the equilibrium states 1,2,3 and 4, I'm going to assume they correspond to the diagram below that typically depicts the Rankine cycle.

[image]

> 1. Why is $Q_{c} = {H_{4}-H_{1}}$ and not $Q_{c} = {H_{1}-H_{4}}$ since the cycle goes from point 4 back to point 1, and a change is
>    defined as $\Delta x=x_{f}-x_{i}$ where f stands for final, and i for
>    initial.

$Q_{c}$ is the same as $\dot Q_{out}$  in the upper diagram below. It is only because the direction of $\dot Q_{out}$ is shown positive leaving the condenser that it is given as the higher enthalpy $H_{4}$ at state 4 minus the lower enthalpy $H_{1}$ at state 1. If the arrow were shown directed into the condenser, then it would equal $H_{1}- H_{4}$.

> 2. Why can we make the approximation that $H_{2} \approx H_{1}$. (Schroeder says that it's a good approximation since the pump adds
>    very little energy to the water, while the $PV$ term in $H$ is very
>    small for liquids.)

Who says we can't? We can, because the change in enthalpy through the pump is generally considered negligible compared to the change in enthalpy at the turbine when calculating net work for determining efficiency.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still don't understand why $H_{2} \approx H_{1}$ is a good approximation, because I'm a little confused, because enthalpy is defined as $H = U + PV$, so since $U$ doesn't change that much I could understand that $U_{1} \approx U_{2}$ but how is $P_{1}V_{1} \approx P_{2}V_{2}$ since as shown on the diagram the pressure increases while volume is constant and so $P_{2}V_{2} \geq P_{1}V_{1}$

Comment: @lynx_s Check out the example problem 1 of the following link which shows the pump work is about 0.6% of the turbine work and therefore can be neglected in the efficiency calculation https://learncheme.com/quiz-yourself/interactive-self-study-modules/rankine-cycle/rankine-cycle-example-problems/

Comment: I don't think you meant to say "compressor.  I think you meant to say "pump".  $\Delta H$ is small in the pump because the temperature is constant for the liquid, so that $\Delta U=0$, and because the specific volume of the liquid is very small compared to a gas, so $v\Delta P$ is very small.

Comment: @ChetMiller yes I meant to say pump as water is considered incompressible

Comment: @lynx_s Since water is essentially incompressible the specific volume at 1 is approximately the same as at 2. So the change in enthalpy is $v\Delta P$. If you do the math as in example 1 of the link for the typical pressures involved, you'll find the enthalpy change at the pump is much smaller than at the turbine.